# Can't get data from Stack Overflow JSON request in JS

Tags: jquery, json

All I'm trying to do is display links to the 20 most recent Stack Overflow Questions, using jQuery to grab the JSON data.

My jQuery...

```
$.getJSON('http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions?pagesize=20', function(data) {
    $.each(data.questions, function(i,data){
        var question_list = '<a href="#">' + data.title + '</a>'; 
        $("div.questions").append(question_list);
    })
});
```

And of course my HTML...

```
<div class=questions></div>
```

Can anyone help with what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The list of `<a>`s simply isn't filling the `<div>` :(

Comment: I doubt your request works in the first place. Check your browser for errors >> . You are trying to access it from a different domain

Comment: you need to use the jsonp to handle the cross-domain issue http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions?pagesize=20&jsonp=?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The StackOverflow API uses [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP):

> All API responses are JSON, we do support JSONP with the **jsonp query parameter**.

*(emphasis mine)*

So you'll need to convert your AJAX call to use `$.ajax` and properly populate the options to make the request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions',
    dataType: 'jsonp',  // let jQuery know this is a JSONP request.
    jsonp: 'jsonp',     // the callback parameter SO uses is called 'jsonp'
    data: {             // options that will get placed in the query string
        pagesize: 20
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.questions, function (i, data) {
            var question_list = '<li><a href="#">' + data.title + '</a></li>';
            $(".questions").append(question_list);
        })
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/QydkZ/1/

I tweaked the success callback to do something a little more readable, but the concept is the same.

---

As a side note, the version of the StackOverflow API you're using is deprecated. This is how you would write this against the 2.1 (current version) of the API:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        pagesize: 20,
        site: 'stackoverflow'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.items, function (i, data) {
            var question_list = '<li><a href="#">' + data.title + '</a></li>';
            $(".questions").append(question_list);
        })
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/k4AnW/1/

I'd highly recommend using the current version of the API instead.

Answer (score 1):

Per the jQuery documentation...

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol. Script and JSONP
>   requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions.

Your ajax request from `xyz.com` can't access data from `stackoverflow.com`

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions?pagesize=20. Origin http://mytest.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

What you can use.

```
<script src="http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions?jsonp=yourCallback"></script>
<script>function yourCallback(JSONdata) { }</script>
```

Comment: I know of the policy, but how does that allow other websites or web apps to pull in outside JSON?

Comment: @JodyHeavener They most likely are using `JSONP`, which is really just a script tag which is *not* subject to the same domain origin policy.

Comment: I don't believe that's the problem, because from his comment it seems like his `<a>` is being filled. If he's getting no data at all, then that's definitely his problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JSONP` [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

From the jQuery docs:

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by
>   the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the
>   discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your data `question_list` is correct before appending.

```
var question_list = '<a href="#">' + data.title + '</a>'; 

// View the question_list in fire bug here by console print and make sure 
// you are correct up to this place.

$("div.questions").append(question_list);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but try

```
$('div.questions').append($(question_list))
```

to make sure it's an appendable object.